# Check if HTTP request is HTTP2?

Tags: go

How to check if a connection to http server was HTTP1.1 or HTTP2?

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  ...
}
```

Comment: `r.ProtoMajor == 2`?

Answer (score 2):

[`http.Request`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request) contains fields for the protocol version:

```
type Request struct {
    // ...

    // The protocol version for incoming server requests.
    //
    // For client requests, these fields are ignored. The HTTP
    // client code always uses either HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2.
    // See the docs on Transport for details.
    Proto      string // "HTTP/1.0"
    ProtoMajor int    // 1
    ProtoMinor int    // 0
    
    // ...
}
```

You can simply check if the `ProtoMajor` field is `2`.

Comment: It keeps saying `1` even if the request is HTTP/2.. `* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x558d5c099cf0)
> POST /create?test=123 HTTP/2`